# Como usar RadioButtons em Xamarin Cross Platform?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml, cross-platform

Sou iniciante no universo `Xamarin`.
Como inserir `RadioButton` para "Masculino" e "Feminino" em `Cross Platform` na xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `RadioButton` é dependente da plataforma. Você terá que fazer o seu, ou [utilizar um já feito por outros programadores](https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML).

Se voce optar por utilizar esse o `xaml` seria o seguinte:

```
//No seu elemento do form
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:XFormsRadioButton.CustomControls;assembly=XFormsRadioButton"

<custom:BindableRadioGroup x:Name="MyRadiouGroup" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sexos}" 
     SelectedIndex="{Binding SexoSelecionado}" VerticalOptions="Start" />
```